# How to make the group box text to be disabled when group box is disabled?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I facing issue with the group box text. I had disabled the groupbox by calling EnableWindow(FALSE), The problem is the group box title is not getting greyed out.

Can anyone please let me know why this is happening and how to get rid off this problem.

Comment: Further to what Michael Walz said below, you could handle WM_CTLCOLOR in the parent and return the grey colour if the group box is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a bug in comctrl32.dll when [visual styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/Controls/cookbook-overview) are enabled.

I've made a very simple program that displays a dialog with an enabled and a disabled group box. Without visual styles the disabled group box is greyed out but with visual styles it is not:

Dialog withhout visual styles:

[image: Without visual styles]

The same dialog using visual styles:

[image: With visual styles]

Both Windows 7 and Windows XP suffer the same problem, I did'nt check on Windows 8. I'm afraid we have to live with that.
The only possibility would be to draw the group box by yourself.

Comment: some dunce at MS decided he/she knew better and everyone should not be allowed to disable group boxes for... reasons.