# winapi - how to disable group box frame with all controls

Tags: winapi

I create a dialog window based on the resource file. I have the following group box:

```
GROUPBOX "Test group",IDC_TEST_GROUP,50,100,200,200
CONTROL  "X",IDC_X,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP,60,120,20,8
CONTROL  "Y",IDC_Y,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,100,120,20,8
```

I would like to disable group box and all controls. The following code disables only buttons:

```
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(h, IDC_TEST_GROUP), false);
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(h, IDC_X), false);
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(h, IDC_Y), false);
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: The group box **is** disabled, but you're probably seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26482595/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [Group Boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-group-boxes)

> **Don't disable group boxes.** To indicate that a group of controls
> doesn't currently apply, disable all the controls within the group
> box, but not the group box itself.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.